# Limit filter upgrader_post_install to a single plugin

Tags: functions, filters

I am using the following filter to run a function that generates a CSS file after a plugin gets updated. Currently the CSS gets generated when any plugin gets updated. Is there a simple way to limit this running to a particular plugin?

```
add_filter('upgrader_post_install', 'generate_my_css', 100, 0);

function generate_my_css() {
    $ss_dir = get_stylesheet_directory();
    $pi_dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
    ob_start();
    require($pi_dir . 'includes/css/mycss.php');
    $css = ob_get_clean();
    file_put_contents($ss_dir . '/css/mycss.css', $css, LOCK_EX);
}
```

Ideally the above code would live in the plugin that was being updated but could just as easily live in the functions.php

Comment: Important things to show in your question when you edit it: 1. Where this code is being initialized. 2. How you have NAMESPACED the very simply named `restore` function. 3. The code that is in the function `restore`;

Comment: Hopefully the above will explain a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`upgrader_post_install`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_post_install/) has three parameters `$response`, `$hook_extra` and `$result` which give you extra information. At the moment I can't take a look myself, but I'm assuming that especially the `$result` variable should give you additional information to differentiate.

Comment: The `$result` actually contained a lot of information but the `$hook_extra` just contained the `plugin_basename` which worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('upgrader_post_install','upgrader_post_install_func',10,3);

function upgrader_post_install_func($response,$hook_extra,$result){
      /*
          visualizar $result y $hook_extra, se guarda en carpeta wp-content.
       */
      
      #file_put_contents(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/test.txt', serialize($result)."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

    /* renombrar complemento actualizado desde github zipball, para mantener 
       actualizaciones dado que github al descargar zip y descomprimirlo lo pone en 
       este formato: <usuario github>-<nombre repo>-<codigo version>
       y se necesita <nombre repo>-<main | master>
    */
    $plugin = explode('/', $hook_extra['plugin']); 
    rename(WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/'. $result['destination_name'],WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/'.$plugin[0]);
    return $result;
}
```

Espero ser de ayuda.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?